# What is wrong with this recursive loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, recursion

Ok so i have this loop

```
def page_children(page)
  content_tag :li do
    link_to page.url, "/#{page.url_path}/#{page.url}"
    if page.children.any?
      content_tag :ul do
        page_children(page)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I keep getting `stack level too deep`

I am using this [gem](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) for my tree structure and my model and haml is the following

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base  
  acts_as_tree :order => 'sort_order'
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Page" 
  scope :parent_nav, lambda{ |navigation| where(:parent_id => nil, :is_home => 0, :nav => navigation).order("sort_order") }
end
```

My haml is the following

```
%ul
 - Page.parent_nav("Attend").each do |page|
 = page_children(page)
```

Basically i want a li for each page and if the page has children then i want another ul with an li for all the children...ext....but my loop is off somehow...any ideas on what im doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write (untested):

```
def render_pages(pages)
  return "" if pages.empty?
  content_tag(:ul) do
    pages.map do |page| 
      content_tag(:li) do
        link = link_to(page.url, helper_to_generate_the_page_path(page))
        link + render_pages(page.children)
      end
    end.join.html_safe
  end
end

= render_pages(Page.parent_nav("Attend"))
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not changing the arguments you give to `page_children` when you call it recursively. Perhaps something like the following (untested):

```
def page_children(page)
  content_tag :li do
    link_to page.url, "/#{page.url_path}/#{page.url}"
    page.children.each do |child|
      content_tag :ul do
        page_children(child)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This needs some polishing, note that helpers return strings, they do not render by performing side-effects like a ERB view.